# Java 8u45 installation unable to locate a Java runtime to invoke

Tags: macos, java

I've downloaded and installed Java JDK 8u45 for OS X 10.10.1 and after the installation has completed (successfully), `java -version` produces the following:

> Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.

Is this an installation bug with this particular version, or have I forgotten to do something?

[image]

```
me@my-laptop$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (0):

Default Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Do you have a $JAVA_HOME environment variable set by any chance? Does `echo $JAVA_HOME` return anything?

Comment: Well that's interesting: $JAVA_HOME is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`. I just bought this mac the other day, java is one of the first things I tried to install. When I initially ran `java -version` it told me it needed to be installed.

Comment: Bingo! Hopefully. :) Find where that is set and remove it. It should be something like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` in a file something like .profile or .bashrc or something along that line in /Users/YOURUSERNAME.

Comment: Ahh... I'm coming from Ubuntu, and I copied over my .bashrc file exactly as is :o I'll have to go over it with a fine-tooth comb. Thanks buddy !

Comment: Have you taken that line out? Is that Java working for you now?

Comment: Oh sorry, yep it's working fine now. That export command was in the bashrc file, I removed it. I'll accept your answer if you like, although maybe you could add something to it. It was just stupidity on my part though, not sure how useful it'll be to anyone else.

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear that worked. I've updated the answer a bit at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means Java can't work out which runtime to use. There can be a few reasons for this.

I've had this error in the past because I had more than one copy of Java installed, and none were selected for use in Java Control Panel.

- Open System Preferences and click on the Java icon this should launch the "Java Control Panel".
- Then select the Java tab and click "View...", this should bring up the "Java Runtime Environment Settings" window.
- My guess is that you'll find more than one instance of Java listed here. Tick the box beside the one you want to use and click OK.

This is from a much older version with a different layout but it should look something like this. Multiple copies listed with tick boxes to tell the system which you want to use.

[image: Example of Java Preferences window]

Another way to check which runtimes you have installed is with the `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` command. Ideally it should return something like the following.

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Failing that you can check whether you have a $JAVA_HOME environment variable set with `echo $JAVA_HOME`. There is a lot of advice online saying you should set this variable but if you do that then I believe it ignores the settings in Java Control Panel.

Comment: It looks like just the one installation, as far as I can tell. Question is updated with screenshot...

Comment: @RTF What happens if you try `/usr/bin/java -version`?

Comment: Same error message "unable to locate..."

Comment: @RTF And if you try `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan you answer got accepted and the OP was very cooperative in Q&A, be a good citizen and give the OP some points for that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't know what you mean by "give the OP some points". Was I not being a good citizen by taking time out of my day to help a stranger fix a problem with their computer? :P

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, yes you were, just a common curtsey, like a hand shake or thank you for been responsive, Up-vote the question or not, the choice is your.